# R shiny selectInput with \r\n

Tags: r, shiny

I'm uploading data from an excel spreadsheet into Shiny which has colnames that include \r\n and selectInput won't let me select them. Is there a workaround in R?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

```
library(shiny)

D = matrix(runif(400), nrow = 20)

colnames(D) = c("PROTECT",                                                                  
                "SAFER\r\nLines",                                                          
                "Name",                                                                     
                "County",                                                                   
                "For Profit",                                                               
                "Health\r\nInspection",                                                     
                "Quality\r\nMeasures",                                                      
                "Staffing",                                                                 
                "2014\r\nCensus",                                                           
                "Total\r\nAdmissions",                                                      
                "% Admissions\r\nw/ LOS: 100+",                                             
                "# of Days\r\nAssessed",                                                    
                "Cumulative\r\nCensus",                                                     
                "% Antibacterial\r\nUsage",                                                 
                "2014 Total\r\nDischarges",                                                 
                "% Discharge\r\nto Hospital",                                               
                "% Discharges to Hospital\r\nw/ Infx based on Primary\r\n& Other Diagnoses",
                "Avg. Elixhauser\r\nScore",                                                 
                "Any MDRO",                                                                 
                "High Frequency of Bath/Shower\r\n(5+ days/wk)")


ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Summaries"),
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("Matching Variables Info",
             sidebarPanel(

               selectInput("col1", "First Column", colnames(D)), 

               selectInput("col2", "Second Column", colnames(D), colnames(D)[19]) 
             ),


             # Show summaries of columns choosen above
             mainPanel(

               verbatimTextOutput("dataInfo")

             )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output){

  output$dataInfo <- renderPrint({
    summary(D[, c(input$col1, input$col2)])
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

`\r\n` is the Windows new line character, presumably because the original data had cells with multiple lines in Excel.

You can convert them to spaces with:

```
colnames(D) <- gsub("\r\n"," ", colnames(D))
```

Comment: Thanks James!! That's quicker than what I found so I'll use it!